# How to convert GpuMat to CvMat in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, gpu

I know how to do the opposite i.e. get `GpuMat` from `CvMat` using upload, but I need a `CvMat` from `GpuMat`, is there any method that can be used for this?

Comment: Did the code helped you ? if not, please let me know that i can correct it. If it did, please accept it...

Comment: i am still trying,don't know if problem is with this or other gpu codes,I am working on realtime GPU SURF will rate soon

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**explicit conversion: Mat -> GPUMat**

```
Mat myMat;
GpuMat myGpuMat;
myGpuMat.upload(myMat); //Via a member function
//Or
GpuMat myGpuMat(myMat) //Via a constructor
//Use myGpuMat here...
```

**implicit conversion: GpuMat -> Mat**

```
GpuMat myGpuMat;
Mat myMat = myGpyMat;
//Use myMat here...
```

Hope it helped,
Julien,

Comment: Too bad original author would not accept, this definitly helped me.

Comment: This seems to work (the original error is gone) but leads to this indeciperable error: 1>cuda beginner.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl cv::gpu::threshold(class cv::gpu::GpuMat const &,class cv::gpu::GpuMat &,double,double,int,class cv::gpu::Stream &)" (?threshold@gpu@cv@@YANAEBVGpuMat@12@AEAV312@NNHAEAVStream@12@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl _tmain(void)" (?_tmain@@YAHXZ)

Comment: @johnktejik, myself a novice in opencv, but did you build your opencv library with GPU support on?

Comment: gpuMat has a method for this:   void download (OutputArray dst) const
  performs download data from device to host memory (Blocking call) so: myGpuMat.download(myMat);

Answer (score 4):

In win 7 , 64 bit, openCV 2.4

`GpuMat` --> `Mat`:

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat dst;
cv::Mat tran(dst);
```

As you can see `dst` is `GpuMat`, and `tran` is `Mat`.

Comment: I get this:  cuda beginner.cpp(15): error C3861: 'tran': identifier not found