# Performing pixel operations with opencv3 cuda bindings

Tags: opencv

I'm wondering if there's any way in the cv::cuda namespace to perform pixel operations using GpuMat. Normally I would do

```
float foo = bar.at<float>(x,y);
```

However, with GpuMat, I can't find its equivalent. I'm getting a compile error that simply says

"class cv::cuda::GpuMat has no member named at"

Answer (score 1):

`GpuMat` holds data in GPU memory. Therefore it can't be accessible from host. That's why you didn't find any pixel access operation.

- For per-pixel access you should download `GpuMat` object first, perform the CPU per-pixel operation and upload it back to GPU memory.
- Anyway, if you access **very few pixels**, then you can use some of the [`cudaMemCopy`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8)* functions to download/upload data. In this case you need to calculate address manually from `GpuMat::data` and `GpuMat::step`

Comment: How would I send the Gpu Mat back to a Cpu Mat?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965465/how-to-convert-gpumat-to-cvmat-in-opencv

Comment: I found my problem, I'm trying to program this on the jetson tk1 and when I upgraded to opencv 3.0.0 the bindings specific to the jetson were erased. The error I was getting that said "function not implemented" was coming from this.